# Using strtok tokens in if statements

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to get my head around how to split arrays and use the tokens in an if statement, however I'm not having much luck.

The below code is for an Arduino.  What I am doing is passing the function receviedChars which will be something like:

> token0,token1,token2

When i print out func, it reads out `c`, so I figured that if I compared func to `c` it should match true.  Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to happen.

I'm quite new to C++ and Arduino, and mainly have a web development background so I might be misinterpreting something

```
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];
```

---

```
char *chars_array = strtok(receivedChars, ",");
char *func = chars_array;

Serial.println(func);
if(func == 'c') {
    Serial.println("It works");
}
```

Could someone help me with where I am going wrong please?

Comment: `func` is a `char *` while `'c'` is a `char`. Different types, and so `func == 'c'` isn't doing what you intended. (I'm a little surprised it even compiled.)

Comment: Your question might be **ambiguous**: do you want `func` to be exactly equal to the string `'c'` or do you want the first character of `func` to match `'c'`? 2 over 4 of the current answers assume the former case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, strtok works iteratively. This means that to split a string into tokens you have to call it until it returns NULL:

```
char* token = strtok(input, ",");

while (token)
{
    ...
    token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
```

And the second thing to know is that char * is just a pointer to a block of memory treated as a string. So when you write something like:

```
char* str = ...;
if (str == 'c')
{
    ...
}
```

This actually means "compare an address pointed by variable 'str' with a value of an ASCII code of character 'c' (which is 0x63 in hex)", therefore your condition will be true iff the pointer returned by strtok equals to 0x63 and that is definitely not what you want.

What you really need is strcmp function, that compares two blocks of memory character by character:

```
char* chars_array = strtok(receivedChars, ",");

if (strcmp(chars_array, "bla") == 0)
{
    // a first token is "bla"
}
```

Comment: *"in C there is no such type as String"* this question is about *Arduino* which has *String*.. I suggest correcting the sentence with *"And the second thing to know is that `char *` is just a **pointer** to a block of memory treated as a string."*

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, fixed that. I was focused on the code snippet which uses those C-style strings, when writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Swap

`if(func == 'c') {`

to

`if(func[0] == 'c') {`

if you want to check if first char is 'c'

Answer (score 0):

'func' is a pointer to the start of an array of characters; comparing it to a character value will almost never yield true.  Perhaps you want to compare the character in that array instead.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you should use  `if(*func == 'c') {`, i.e. dereference pointer `func`, instead of `if(func == 'c') {`.
Note that you additionally should consider that `chars_array` might be an empty string or might comprise only `','`-characters; in this case, `strtok` will yield `NULL`, and probably lets your app crash. Hence, the code should look as follows:

```cpp
if (func != nullptr) {
  Serial.println(func);
  if(*func == 'c') {
      Serial.println("It works"); 
  }
}
```